# Magento 2 Load checkout-cart_configure for different Product page Layout

Tags: magento2, addtocart

My website has 5 types of layout of page,in which 4 types layout of Configure Product and 1 type is Simple Product Page.

I am loading these layout by observer by checking the current category/product page and on the basis of that loading the layout file.

```
     $layout = $observer->getLayout();
     $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_id_2087');
```

Everyting is working fine on product page.

Now when I am going to cart page and edit any item from cart page then it call layout file "checkout_cart_configure.xml" file and when open this file you will find code :

```
<update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_cart_configure_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

So my question is you can see the code "" so it called default catalog_product_view.xml file.But in my code there are 5 types xml files.  e.g  catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml , catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml , catalog_product_view_id_123.xml .....etc.

So it is not called my above files in "checkout_cart_configure.xml" .Hence updatecart.phtml file is not called.

Please let me know in this situation how can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this problem by calling different layout file  "checkout_cart_configure.xml" for different product layout.

I do this with event observer **layout_load_before** .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_product_layout" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" disabled="false"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

in LayoutLoadBefore.php file code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
         $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        if ($observer['full_action_name'] == 'checkout_cart_configure') {

            if (!$product) {
                return $this;
            }

                if ($product->getName() == 'Test1') { 
                    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('checkout_cart_configure_645');
                } elseif ($product->getName() == 'Test2') { 
                    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('checkout_cart_configure_839');
                else {
                    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                       $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('checkout_cart_configure_configurable');
                }
            }
        }
   return $this;
    }

}
```

Now Create checkout_cart_configure files in Magento_Checkout/layout folder.

Now update handle in checkout_cart_configure.xml :

```
<update handle="catalog_product_view_simple_product"/> //Name as per your handle
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_cart_configure_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```